# rename file only in specific subfolder with python

Tags: python, rename, subdirectory, os.walk, os.path

I've got a path with multiple folders each beginning with 'P' and ending with an individual number ('P001'-'P104'). Each of those folders has two subfolders 'subfolder1' and 'subfolder2' both containing "file_1.nii" and "file_2.nii". I want to rename "file_1.nii" into "new_name.nii" only in subfolder1, but not in subfolder2.

This code works for renaming files in all the subfolders:

```
import os

mainpath = 'M:/path'

def replace(folder_path, old, new):
   for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
       for name in files: 
           if(old.lower() in name.lower()):
              file_path = os.path.join(path, name)
              new_name = os.path.join(path, name.lower().replace(old,new))
              os.rename(file_path, new_name)

replace(mainpath, 'file_1.nii', 'new_name.nii')
```

but it would rename 'file_1.nii' in all subfolders. Does anyone know how to extend the code, so it does only rename the file in a specific subfolder or does anyone know an alternative solution?

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your if condition to

```
if(old.lower() in name.lower() and 'subfolder2' not in path.lower()):
    <rest of the code>
```

This should meet the objective if all your nested second subfolder has same name , which is 'subfolder2'

Update(2021/03/25):

it works for me

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. The code runs through but it's still changing the file-name in subfolder2 aswell

Comment: @valid It works well for me. Updated the answer with screen shot

Comment: I've replicated the path, folders and files the way they are in your screenshot and then it works. In reality, though, my path is a bit more complex: Subfolder1 has another subfolder until the subfolder with the data. Subfolder2 though doesn't have subfolders in between. Could that be the problem? Also, the mainpath is a bit longer. Anyways, thank you for your help so far @akhil pathirippily

Comment: nested directories under subfolder1 or subfolder2 doesn't cause any problem to the logic since we are checking " 'subfolder2' not in path" . If it's renaming all files , it means this condition is getting true somehow , means somehow 'subfolder2' substring is getting  missed or escaped from your path string value  .

Comment: If my answer helped you , you can accept the anwer